# By definition, by the definition

Tags: articles, mathematics

I am confused how to use "by definition" in mathematics.

When I want to say that some fact follows from Definition of A, then can I say:

1. This fact follows by definition.
2. This fact follows by definition of A.
3. This fact follows by the definition of A.

If I use the sentence 1, does the meaning different from 2 or 3 (if these make sense).

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that the use of '**by definition**' requires a particular set-up when describing the steps in a mathematical problem, i.e. there has to be an actual definition involved, and tends to adhere to the following format.

> A rectangle is a polygon with four sides and four right angles.
>
> A square is a polygon with four equal sides and four right angles.
>
> Therefore, **by definition**, a square is a type of rectangle.

In other words, the expression 'by definition' has a narrow scope It means that what you are about to say must be true. Not just *is* true, or *happens* to be true, but *must* be.

To return to the examples you have given. In my opinion, both 1 and 2 are valid statements, though they aren't overly natural in their structure. 2 is certainly more specific - it directly references A, but if A is implicit in the overall statement, then it can be omitted from the sentence.

For example:

1. > A rectangle is a polygon with four sides and four right angles.
   >
   > A square is a polygon with four equal sides and four right angles.
   >
   > Therefore, a square is a type of rectangle. This fact follows by
   >   definition.
2. > Fact A: A rectangle is a polygon with four sides and four right
   >   angles.
   >
   > Fact B: A square is a polygon with four equal sides and four right
   >   angles.
   >
   > Therefore, a square is a type of rectangle. This fact follows by
   >   definition of A.

The construction seems odd, but it works. The format in my first example would arguably be more recognisable though.

Mathematical problems, particularly mathematical papers, tend to follow a specific syntax and structure. the following paper provides a nice collection of these, and my prove useful.

[Writing Mathematical Papers in English - A Practical Guide](http://www.m-fozouni.ir/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Writing-Mathematical-Papers-in-English_-A-Practical-Guide-European-Mathematical-Society-2005.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is "by the definition of A" incorrect?

Comment: *'by definition'* is idiomatic, *'by **the** definition'* is not.

Comment: If a definition is numbered, like "Definition 1.2", then can I still say "by Definition 1.2"?